# Mapping <c-w> to be "<c-w>w" in Vim

Tags: vim, vim-plugin

I am having trouble to activate the following mappings:

```
  nnoremap <buffer> <C-K> <c-w>w
  nnoremap <buffer> <C-S-K> <c-w>W
```

Where, I want have "pressing Ctrl+K in normal mode" to send me to the next buffer (of the same screen), in a clockwise way. `<c-w>W` in Vim will go the other direction. I want to map this action to be `Ctrl+Shift+w`.

Any idea why the mapping fails? I found only the latex-suite.vim has a mapping of `<c-w>` and none `<c-s-w>` has been mapped. The plugin mapping is buffer only.

Thank you for your input.

All the best,

-Linfeng

Comment: Just a guess, but `<buffer>`'d mappings only apply to the current buffer. Maybe if you source your vimrc in a buffer you want to apply it to, it'd work.

Comment: Or drop the `<buffer>` prefix entirely?

Comment: Which of the two mappings fails? Or do they both fail?

Comment: Thank you all. `<buffer>` will screw the pairs of mapping. And, Vim don't like <C-S-W>.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the `<buffer>` keyword, your mappings only apply to the current buffer. So, when you have these in `~/.vimrc`, they aren't effective, and if you type them in, you would need to have the same current buffer visible in multiple window splits. I don't think that's what you want. Instead, define them to be global mappings:

```
nnoremap <C-K> <c-w>w
nnoremap <C-J> <c-w>W
```

Edit: I've replaced `<C-S-K>` with `<C-J>`, because shifted control sequences are generally not available in Vim, unfortunately.

They could still be overwritten by some filetype plugins using `nnoremap <buffer> <C-K>`.

#### Alternative

I'd prefer the following set of directional mappings. They provide more precision, at the cost of wasting more keys:

```
nnoremap <C-j> <c-w>j
nnoremap <C-k> <c-w>k
nnoremap <C-h> <c-w>h
nnoremap <C-l> <c-w>l
```

Comment: I didn't think Vim could recognize <C-S-anything> separately from <C-anything>.

Comment: @Ben: You're right, so probably an alternative key would be needed for the backwards thing. Edited my answer. Thanks!

Comment: Alternatively, you can often alt-mappings instead of ctrl-mappings if you want to use modified shifted keys.

Comment: Given that <C-S-anything> is not recognized by Vim, I think I can implement

Comment: @Ben, given that <C-S-anything> won't be recognized by Vim in any way, I think I will implement it in AHK (AutoHotKey) for Vim window specifically. Thank you for confirming this.

Comment: @IngoKarkat: thank you for pointing out the usage of <buffer>. I've been used to put it in my key-mappings so that I won't screw up mappings across different file types. I would rather reserve the <C-J> mapping, as Vim-Latex-Suite uses that for "jumping to the next placeholder <++>". Thanks anyway!